# Php error log message about _SESSION not being a defined variable

Tags: php

I use _SESSION in many parts of my application, but for some reason, my error logs keep having this line in there:

```
Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

Does anyone know why it outputs that and how I can stop that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hm... did you try

```
session_start();
```

on the first line?

Answer (score 2):

it should be `$_SESSION` not `_SESSION`

Comment: I thought that was it - but actually, here is what I use: $variablexyz = $_SESSION['param'];

Comment: then as @royrui says. You should start with session_start();